# iOS Swift UiView frame changes in a weird manner

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I am working on a project, and I am developing a login screen that has UIView of two textfields and I change the position of that view when keyboard hides or shows.

I am getting a problem when I move from the email textfield to the password text field. The view return to its original location/frame without asking it to.

Here's code snippet:

```
var isKeyboardOpened = false
@IBOutlet weak var viewLoginContainer: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}


func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if !isKeyboardOpened {
                isKeyboardOpened = true
                self.viewLoginContainer.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height - 100
                self.viewLoginContainer.layoutIfNeeded()

        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            isKeyboardOpened = false
            self.viewLoginContainer.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - 100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set layout constraints programmatically with Auto Layout, to persist your desired layout.

Comment: Why are you checking `self.view.frame.origin.y` ??

Comment: this was a solution on web and I was so  frustrated but I removed it and it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by editing the constrains programmatically by adding:

```
self.viewLoginContainer_topConstraint.constant = x
```